# Raise the Event for object Collection

Tags: c#

How to raise the event if a Collection is modified. Type is object like:

```
public object Source
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

I want to raise the NotifyCollectionChangedEvent for Source in OnPropertyChanged

Comment: No idea why Source is a System.Object, but (from the looks of it) you can cast it to INotifyCollectionChanged and all call CollectionChanged. Thought you should do that at the source, do not use automatic properties, use Source as a proxy property to get to your inner object and call CollectionChanged there. What are you trying to do anyway?

Answer (score 1):

```
private object _Source;
public object Source
{
    get{
        return this._Source;
    }
    set{
        this._Source = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Source");
    }
}
```